# jQuery: triggers do not fire on elements loaded with .load()

Tags: javascript, events, triggers, jquery

I have index.php and use jQuery .load() to load content from load.php.

When I trigger an event on elements that are in the index.php, the event fires. On the same elements, when loaded with .load() into index.php the events do not fire!?

Why? Am I doing sth wrong?

If I preview the page with e.g. FireBug, the #id of the element is exactly like it should be, but not even a function like this works:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

The same function works, if the element is placed in the index.php and not loaded with .load(). Any ideas??

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did you wrap the function with document ready? I am not sure, but I think when ajax is loaded the event will not be triggered in that case... can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `click` event binder does not bind to any elements created after execution.  You can add a `click` listener immediately following the `.load()` method, or you can use something like `live` or `delegate` to bind to element patterns in the DOM.

Comment: will this mean, that if there is the same element (e.g. #clickme) already in index.php, but after .load() it will be replaced by another #clickme, this would work?

Comment: Hmmm... I think if you destroyed the element and then recreated it, it would destroy the event listener, but probably not recreate it; I'm not sure, but it's easy to avoid the issue altogether by using `live()` instead of `click()`.

Comment: oh, ok.. thank you very much for your fast answers! :) I tried with the example from .live() on the jquery side and this works fine: $("a.offsite").live("click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); }); So, thank you again! :)

Comment: Don't use `live` or `delegate` in current versions of `jquery`, they have been replaced by `on`.

Comment: You should use `on()` rather than `live()`: [As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: You are assuming he's using 1.7+, but it's sound advice.

Comment: If he's not using 1.7+ then `delegate` is preferable over `live` if at all possible.

Comment: I am using 1.7+, however cannot get .on() to work... is there something wrong with this syntax: `$("#clickme").on("click", function(){ alert("hello!"); });`?

Comment: @Chris yes, look at James Montagne's post: `$("#clickmeParentThatWontChange").on("click", "#clickme" , function(){})`

Comment: @steveax: ah, thank you for the explanation with #clickmeParentThatWontChange!! :) now I got it :) Thx a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `click` will create an event listener on the element at the time it is called.  if the element does not exist at the time `click` is called the listener is not created.  You need to use event delegation using `on` (or `delegate` in older versions of jquery).

Have a look at the [on documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and read about delegation.  You'll need something like this:

```
$("<selector of static ancestor>").on("click", "#clickme" , function(){})
```

Comment: sorry, if I do not understand right away... in your example, James, what is <selector of static ancestor>?

Comment: It's a selector to an ancestor element of `#clickme` which is not dynamically loaded.  Some element which is there on load.  If nothing else it can be `document`, though something more specific is prefered.